# Can I play without a DVD Drive?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-iv, physical-media

I bought GTA IV - EFLC today.
I have got **2 DVDs and CD-Key.** (also a printed map and manual. I like it.)
**What I don't have yet is a DVD Drive on my Gaming Rig.**

Any Ideas on how to run it?

Can I make iso files of the DVDs from my laptop and use them.
Did anyone try this? Did it work?

Does shared network drive work?
http://www.howtogeek.com/114254/how-to-share-cd-dvd-drives-over-the-network-on-windows/

Comment: did u try a virtual DVD-ROM (or mounting an ISO)?

Answer (score 2):

You need to have the the game's DVD-ROM in a DVD drive attached to your laptop. The PC version of GTA IV uses a disk check as part of its copy protection. There's no way around this without defeating this copy protection measure, something we can't help you with here.

Connecting a USB DVD drive to your PC should allow you to play the game. Alternatively the Steam version of GTA IV doesn't require a disk in the drive, but that would be mean buying a second copy of the game.

Comment: Doesn't the disk version need to be activated on Steam anyway? In that case, the game could be downloaded from Steam, no? I don't know because I bought the Steam version.

Comment: @Nolonar No, the disk version doesn't use Steam. The CD key won't work with Steam.

Comment: does shared drive work? http://www.howtogeek.com/114254/how-to-share-cd-dvd-drives-over-the-network-on-windows/

Comment: @rahulroy9202 Unfortunately that won't work. The copy protection drivers need to be able to talk directly to the drive in order to verify that the DVD hasn't been copied.

Answer (score 0):

Since March 19, 2020 all of the Retail game copies can be activated on Steam or the Rockstar Games Social Club to activate Grand Theft Auto IV: Complete Edition. From the Steam Page:

> Games not previously activated using Games for Windows Live will be able to use the Key on the back of the game manual to activate and update to Grand Theft Auto IV: Complete Edition

Activating the Retail copy of Episodes from Liberty City on Steam or the RGL will automatically give you GTA IV and vice versa for free.